# Is it possible for Flink CEP SQL to run on a hopping window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep

My typical use case is to keep monitoring an event stream to detect event patterns, but I expect the window is a hopping one. By default, `interval ...` in CEP SQL should define a tumbling window. Is it possible to have a hopping window for CEP pattern matching? or any other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to nest time-based queries in Flink SQL. So you can define a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause on a view that did a windowing before.

Here is some sketch example:

```sql
-- get the rowtime from the window operation
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT HOP_ROWTIME(rowtime, INTERVAL '1' SECOND, INTERVAL '2' SECOND) AS windowedRowtime, ...
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY HOP(rowtime, INTERVAL '1' SECOND, INTERVAL '2' SECOND);

-- use the new rowtime for MATCH_RECOGNIZE
SELECT * FROM my_view MATCH_RECOGNIZE(ORDER BY windowedRowtime ...)
```

Comment: In this case, I don't need to write `interval ..` in MATCH_RECOGNIZE, right?

Comment: Interval within a match recognize clause is a timeout to clean up stale state while waiting for the final end event.

Comment: A further question, the created view only contains the aggregate values and group-by fields. what if i need all raw rows to feed into match_recognize?

Answer (score 1):

If by "Flink CEP SQL" you mean MATCH_RECOGNIZE, then the `WITHIN INTERVAL` constraint doesn't really map onto any specific kind of windowing. You can use whichever [AFTER MATCH](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html#after-match-strategy) strategy meets your needs.

Comment: i don't understand how `after match` can help in this case. can you give an example?Thx